# MySql query code to fetch unique data from single ID

Tags: mysql, database

How do i List the CUSTNUMs and NAMES of any customer who has **only** ordered chemical [NUMBER].

`ORDERS` TABLE

```
+---------+--------+------------+------+
| CUSTNUM | CHEMNO | DATE       | QTY  |
+---------+--------+------------+------+
|  123456 |   1234 | 2000-00-00 |   35 |
+---------+--------+------------+------+
```

`CUSTOMER` TABLE

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| CUSTNUM | NAME      | LOCATION  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  123456 | AmChem    | New York  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join the `CUSTOMER` and `ORDERS` tables containing orders for a particular `<chemno>` with a subquery for the custnum that buy only a product:

```
SELECT
    CUSTNUM, NAME 
FROM
    CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN
    ORDERS o ON o.CUSTNUM = c.CUSTNUM and o.CHEMNO = <chemno>
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT
          CUSTNUM 
      FROM
          ORDERS
      GROUP BY
          CUSTNUM 
      HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT CHEMNO) = 1 ) t ON t.CUSTNUM = o.CUSTNUM
```

Answer (score 1):

I will approach this with one `join` between both tables, then grouping by the column `CUSTNUM` of the `ORDERS` table and finally adding the required conditions on the `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
SELECT
    o.CUSTNUM,
    c.NAME
FROM
    ORDERS AS o
INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER AS c ON c.CUSTNUM = o.CUSTNUM
GROUP BY
    o.CUSTNUM
HAVING
    ( COUNT(DISTINCT o.CHEMNO) = 1 AND MIN(o.CHEMNO) = <some_chemno> )
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, slow day...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.custnum 
  FROM orders x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders y 
    ON y.custnum = x.custnum 
   AND y.chemno <> x.chemno 
 WHERE x.chemno = 9377 
   AND y.order_id IS NULL;
```

The rest of this task has been left as an exercise for the reader